# Writing one file with two functions in vba

Tags: vba, filesystems

This is the header of my main function to write excel cells to an XML file. I want this to call another function, which can do its own set of writing.

```
Public Sub WriteXML()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim xmlFile

xmlFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & 'Test1' & ".xml"

Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sht1")
Open xmlFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & _
          " encoding=" & Chr(34) & "UTF-8" & Chr(34) & "?>"
Call WriteCustomer(xmlFile)
```

This is the start of the second function, though I'm getting an 'object not found' sort of error.

```
Sub WriteCustomer(x As Variant)

Print x, "         <Customer>"
Print x, "             <First>" & 'Bill' & "</First>"
Print x, "             <Last>" & 'Johnson' & "</Last>"
Print x, "         </Customer>"
Print x, ""
End Sub
```

How do I need to construct the call and/or variable to pass the open file as an object to the second function?

Comment: You have opened the file as #1 - so you need to print to #1, not to xmlFile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can request, store and pass around a handle as follows:

```
Dim handle As Integer
handle = FreeFile()

Open xmlFile For Output As #handle
   Print #handle, "<?xml version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & _

...
Call WriteCustomer(handle)
```

And

```
Sub WriteCustomer(handle As Integer)
   Print #handle, "         <Customer>"
```

Comment: What does the # do in this context too?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have opened the file in the first function with the line

```
Open xmlFile For Output As #1
```

Any code that references #1 while it's open will write to the same file. Thus you can simply rewrite your second function as

```
Sub WriteCustomer()
  Print #1, "         <Customer>"
  Print #1, "             <First>" & 'Bill' & "</First>"
  Print #1, "             <Last>" & 'Johnson' & "</Last>"
  Print #1, "         </Customer>"
  Print #1, ""
End Sub
```